# Convergence of $\frac{\cos(x)}{n\sin(x)}$ an n$\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So I have this as my homework in Measure Theory and I don't know how to prove it. The question is the following:
On the domain $\Omega = (0, \pi)\times {\rm I\!R}$ we have a function defined as: 
\begin{equation}
\phi_{n}(x,y) = \frac{\cos(x)}{n\sin(y)} \qquad if\,\,y\in {\rm I\!R}\setminus \{k\pi | k\in {\rm I\!N} \} \\ \phi_{n}(x,y)=n^2 \,\,\,\,\,\,\qquad if\,\,y\in \{k\pi | k\in {\rm I\!N} \}.
\end{equation}
Now I need to prove that the sequence
\begin{equation}
\{\int_{\Omega}|\phi_{n}(x,y)|dxdy\}
\end{equation}

is convergent almost everywhere. I know that since $\{ k\pi | k\in {\rm I\!N}\}$ is just a set of disjoint points, its Lebesgue measure is $0$, hence, we don't care about them.  I was specifically told that I should use Fatou's lemma which we can apply due to the absolute sign. Thus, since we have sequence of positive functions we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega}\lim \inf |\phi_{n}| \leq \lim \inf \int_{\Omega}|\phi_{n}|.
\end{equation}
Also, we have the inverse inequality for the $\lim \sup$ as well i.e.
\begin{equation}
\lim \sup \int_{\Omega}|\phi_{n}| \leq \int_{\Omega}\lim \sup |\phi_{n}|.
\end{equation}
Then, if the $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ coincide, we have that the sequence is actually converges and we get that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega}\lim \inf |\phi_{n}| = \lim \int_{\Omega} |\phi_{n}| = \int_{\Omega}| \lim \sup |\phi_{n}|.
\end{equation}
However, I am stuguling with how to use the properties of $\phi_{n}$ to show that $\lim \inf = \lim \sup$. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Look at the expression for $\phi_n(x,y)$. What does it converge to almost everywhere?

Comment: I know that it converges to 0, but I assumed that I should not know that, and by just using some properties of sin and cos we can prove that limsup and liminf are the same.

Comment: Why did you assume that? The pointwise a.e. limit doesn't really have anything to do with sin and cos, that's kind of the "trick" with problems like this. At a.e. point $(x,y)$ its just a sequence of the form $const.\times 1/n$

Comment: So then I should just show that liminf = 0 and limsup = 0, if yes then please post it as an answer and when I am done with the proof (probably tomorrow), then I accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=\{k\pi : k\in\mathbb N\}$ then $|Y|=0$ so by Fubini theorem
$$
\int_{\Omega} |\phi_n(x, y)|dxdy = \frac 1n\int_{\Omega\setminus Y}\left\lvert\frac{\cos x}{\sin y}\right\rvert dxdy=\frac 1n\int^\pi_0\lvert\cos x\rvert dx\int_{\mathbb R\setminus Y}\left\lvert\frac{1}{\sin y}\right\rvert dy=
$$

Now
$$
\int_{\mathbb R\setminus Y}\left\lvert\frac{1}{\sin y}\right\rvert dy=\sum^{+\infty}_{i=-\infty}\int^{(i+1)\pi}_{i\pi}\left\lvert\frac{1}{\sin y}\right\rvert dy=\sum^{+\infty}_{i=-\infty}\int^{\pi}_{0}\left\lvert\frac{1}{\sin y}\right\rvert dy=+\infty
$$

and doesn't converge

Comment: That is true, $\int |1/\sin(y)|$ $\rightarrow \infty$ but as was pointed out by @T_M, we can consider $\int |1/sin(y)|$ as a constant for all $y \in R\setminus Y$ which is less than $\infty$ and as n $\rightarrow \infty$ we indeed get that $\int |\phi_{n}(x,y)|$ converges to 0, don't we?

Comment: The integral doesn't converge for all $n$, if $\frac{1}{\lvert\sin y\rvert}$ is integrated on a set smaller than $\mathbb R$ (like compact set) the integral _may_ be considered as a finite constant